# Парсер текстового файла

Tags: php, парсер

Как сделать парсер? Есть текстовые файлы в большом количестве, нужно, чтобы можно было считать некоторые элементы из строк и записать в другой текстовый файл.

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```
<?php

$data_array = file('справка030312.txt');
foreach ($data_array as $k => $v) {
    echo 'Строка номер ' . ($k + 1) . ' содержит данные: ' . $v . '<br/>';
}

$content = $buff; // хотел написать сверху, чтобы читать из строки элементы и хранить в буфере, а потом запись
$f       = fopen('справка.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($f, $content);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: Это явно похоже на работу за автора.

Что непонятно тебе в твоём же вопросе? На какие камни наткнулся? или еще даже не приступал?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: ну прочесть ты смог судя по всему (если $content где-то определяется), по каким критериям ты хочешь выбирать "некоторые элементы"?

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно сделать парсер для обычного текстового файла, то парсер изобретать не обязательно, достаточно воспользоваться генератором парсеров: [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser)